# How to Programatically Add UsersControl to TabControl on Button Click - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am struggling to add UserControl to WPF TabItem on button click. Before achieving this i was using hidden and visible properties of each TabItem  using button click event handler like folloiwng:-

```
  FirstTabItem.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
  FirstTabItem.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
```

This does not fulfill my need so i want to programmatically add TabItem  to TabControl using button click. Please anyone help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this very simple by using the following code

```
            var tabItem = new TabItem();
            tabItem.Header = "My Tab Header";
            tabItem.Content = new UserControl1();
            MainTabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
```